# A Build Issue when using gradle

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to build a opensource Java project, lilith, with gradle. But meet this problem when runing gradle from cmd line window:

```
D:\Opensource\lilith_svn\sulky-master>gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'sulky-master'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve org.apache.maven.wagon:wagon-webdav-jackrabbit:1.0-beta-6
.
     Required by:
         :sulky-master:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/wagon/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit/1.0-beta-6/wagon-webdav-jackrabbit-1.0-beta-6.pom'.
         > Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused
      > Could not resolve com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.4.
     Required by:
         :sulky-master:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin/0.4/gradle-versions-plugin-0.4.pom'.
         > Connection to http://repo1.maven.org refused

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 44.897 secs
```

I found I can access the destination file from my web browser. So I'm confused about the error message about the connection failure.

Or does that mean the gradle program does not have the right to access internet?  If so, please give some workaround for it.

Thanks,
Terry.

Comment: You should use gradlew, and not gradle, to build the project. That will make sure you use the appropriate version of gradle: the one used by the project. Regarding the connection issue, you probably use a proxy to connect to the web with your browser. See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html for how to configure the proxy for gradle

Comment: When i use gradlew, the connection exception msg was there in downloading gradle-1.8-bin.zip.
Is there any workaround if I can't use network?

Comment: Regarding the connection issue, you probably use a proxy to connect to the web with your browser. See gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html for how to configure the proxy for gradle

Answer (score 13):

Open gradle.properties and add the following

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.http.proxyPort=3213
systemProp.https.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
systemProp.https.proxyPort=3213
```

(Your settings might be different. My case was I was sharing a VPN connection by Astrill from another computer. See http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html for more information.)

Comment: Some how the gradle.properties file is not create automaticaly. You have to create it on your own in our PROJECT/platforms/android folder.

Comment: THANK YOU :) MAN IT WORKS LIKE A CRAZY

Answer (score 2):

To add to what @Bugs Bunny said:

If you have set `“GRADLE_USER_HOME”` environment variable pointing to `C:\Documents and Settings\myAccount\.gradle` you can put `gradle.properties` in that `.gradle` directory.

A copy of `gradle.properties` file can be found at
`C:\gradle-2.13\samples\userguide\tutorial\properties\gradle.properties`.

But it doesn't have the `proxyHost` settings.

I would add the following to gradle.properties:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy_address
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=my_user_name
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=my_secret_password

systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy_address
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=my_user_name
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=my_secret_password
```

Answer (score 0):

**2022 update**

In the latest version of `gradle`, you may not find `gradle.properties`.
You can find instead `./gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.

Append the proxy information in this file:

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=<your proxy>
systemProp.http.proxyPort=<your port>
systemProp.https.proxyHost=<your proxy>
systemProp.https.proxyPort=<your port>
```